# Gaussian expectations

Tags: definite-integrals, random-variables, normal-distribution, expectation

I am trying to find a closed form solutions or approximations for following Expectations:

Suppose $\theta$ is a Gaussian Random Variable, i.e $\theta \sim  N(o,\sigma^2_{\theta})$

\begin{equation}
E_{\theta} [\Phi(\frac{a-\theta}{\sqrt{b\theta^2+c}}     )]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
E_{\theta} [    \frac{\partial {(\Phi(\frac{a-\theta}{\sqrt{b\theta^2+c}}     ))}}{\partial{\theta}}]
\end{equation}

where $\Phi(.)$ is the CDF of a standard Gaussian Variable and $b>0, c >0 $

Comment: If $b\ne0$ there is little hope to achieve anything (if $b=0$ this was already asked on the site). In the second formula, what does the derivative mean? Keep in mind that $\theta$ is a random variable, not a simple real number.

Comment: @Did I don't see any problem with derivative, consider the term in brackets a function of $\theta$ that we are trying to get the expectation of that.

Comment: You "do not see any problem" because you did not think this through. For a suitable function $G$, we are looking at $H(\theta)=\Phi(G(\theta))$. Do you intend that $$\frac{\partial\Phi(G(\theta))}{\partial\theta}=(\Phi\circ G)'(\theta)=G'(\theta)\,\varphi(G(\theta))\ ?$$ Then say so...

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get the expectation of $G'(\theta) \phi(G(\theta))$